# Why is it called as a "1 bit" binary full adder?

Tags: digital-logic, adder

[image]

Where does the naming of this circuit come from?

Comment: You can combine two half adders with an or gate to form a full adder. I have no idea who used the term for the first time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is named like that because it can add two 1-bit numbers with a carry bit input from previous adder, and outputs one 1-bit number and a carry output to next adder.

It is a fully functional adder for one bit, and multiple full adders can be expanded calculate a sum of two multi-bit numbers.

Comment: hmmm, so it is related to the data size of operands?

Comment: Yes, one adder for adding two one-bit numbers. 8 adders for adding two 8-bit numbers.

Comment: then it would be called as 8 bit full adder, right?

Comment: Maybe, depends on how you want to look at it. A single adder block diagram for adding two 8-bit numbers would be a 8-bit full adder. But it might internally be simply made of eight one-bit full adders.

Answer (score 0):

A half-adder has 2 inputs, A & B, and generates 2 outputs, S (sum) and Cout (Carry).

A full adder, which is what you've shown, has a 3rd input, Cin.

You need to use full adders to build a multi-bit adder, except for the lowest term where you could get by with a half adder.